# Re-Install MacOS Sierra

Tags: macos, install

I have 2017 MacBook Air, which has been upgrade to Mojave. Sierra was installed at the time of purchase.

Now, I need to refresh the Mac as brand new device. Therefore, I am trying to erase the hard disk. Below is a image of the Disk Utility. Which is the one to be erased? Are they 2 hard disks or 1?

I was able to erase the AppleAPF, but was unable to do anything with the Apple SSD, which appears to be unformatted.

[image]

After erasing the AppleAPFS, I started the installation process, but this took a very long time (lots of hours) with nothing moving. I do not know if this because my internet connection is very week or due to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select AppleAPFS on the top, click Erase but if you try to run recovery option, it will install Mojave again. So to have Sierra, I would suggest the following steps:

- First, connect your Macbook with an ethernet cable as it takes an hour to get full installation (basically depends upon the internet speed also).
- After this, turn off your computer and Reinstall from macOS Recovery mode with a combination of **Shift-Option-⌘-R** (this allows to install the macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version still available.)

**Basically, as per Apple Guidance:**

**Command (⌘)-R**
Install the latest macOS that was installed on your Mac.

**Option-⌘-R**
Upgrade to the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac.

**Shift-Option-⌘-R**
Install the macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version still available.

Let me know how it goes.